# Boost logging - getting unresolved symbol

Tags: boost, cmake

I am a novice to cmake and boost so this question might be missing something obvious:

I am building a project with cmake on linux (ubuntu) and I am trying to use boost logging in that project. Here is what I do to generate the Makefile:

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lpthread -std=c++11" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lpthread" -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lpthread" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -std=c++11"
```

Compile goes through fine. (Some of these flags may be overkill -- I should only need the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS).

When I run the executable, I get the following unresolved reference:

```
-- ImportError: /home/mranga/gr-msod-sensor/gr-msod_sensor/build/lib/libgnuradio-msod_sensor.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix3aux25unhandled_exception_countEv
```

What flags am I missing? My boost library is set up and LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the right location.

When I manually built a test program using the same linker flags, it compiles and runs fine so boost is installed correctly. I hope I have not missed the obvious.

(Moved question from [the GNU Radio mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-10/msg00190.html) -- sorry if you are reading this post for a second time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be linking against the non-multithreaded version:

```
-lboost_log
```

but the run-time linker seems to explicitely look for the *multithreaded* variant ([the Boost doc site on that](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html)):

```
_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix3aux25unhandled_exception_countEv
                  ^^
```

My guess hence is that you should try linking with

```
-lboost_log_mt
```

but the question whether that is right or not depends too much on your individual project to make it possible for me to clearly answer this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the order of libraries in the linker command line in `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is incorrect. boost_log_setup depends on boost_log, so boost_log_setup should go first.